# Ambient Module writeable property

Tags: typescript

I want to use a JavaScript AMD module coming from another team in my TypeScript file. For that I create an OtherModule.d.ts file like this:

```
declare module 'some/Path/OtherModule' {

    ...

    export let someProperty : string;

    ...

}
```

In my TypeScript file I have to modify the value of that *someProperty*. That's how the module works, I can't change that. So I do like this:

```
import * as OtherModule from 'some/Path/OtherModule';

...

OtherModule.someProperty = "I want to set something here";

...
```

But TypeScript doesn't like that. I get the following error:

Cannot assign to 'someProperty' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

Notice I didn't use *const* or *readonly* in the d.ts file. So what is going on? And how can I use this module in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how ES6 modules work. Imports are considered constants and can only be modified by the module that exports them.

If you want to set the value, you'll have to include a setter in the `OtherModule.d.ts` that sets the value.

```
export function setSomeProperty(newPropertyValue: string) {
    someProperty = newPropertyValue;
}
```

and then call it after it's been imported.

If you can't modify the source `*.d.ts` file, it should be possible to use `require()` syntax instead for you import, which will allow you to modify the property.

Comment: As I said, I can't modify the original interface. And the module is not truly constant. That value would be set if I was using JavaScript. I know it might not be a good practice, but I still have to work with it.

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: `(OtherModule as any).someProperty = "foo"` should also work. But even though you can get around TS' warning I wouldn't advise it. ES6 doesn't allow this, that's why TS is warning you. The only reason it "works" is because of down-compiling to ES5 and a non ES6 spec compliant emulated module system.